# Aplicación descargada desde la Play store no funciona en equipos de usuarios finales

Tags: android, google-maps

Tengo una aplicación android que cuando la descarga un usuario desde la play store no funciona el mapa, pero instalada desde mi pc funciona todo perfecto.

Este es mi código.

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    //private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
       // mMap = googleMap;
        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
       /* LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
       */
        Bundle coordenadas = getIntent().getExtras();
        Double latitud=Double.parseDouble(coordenadas.getString("latitud"));
        Double longitud=Double.parseDouble(coordenadas.getString("longitud"));
        String nombre=coordenadas.getString("nombre");
        String direccion=coordenadas.getString("direccion");
        System.out.println(nombre);
        System.out.println(direccion);    
        LatLng mapaEmpresa = new LatLng(latitud,longitud);    
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mapaEmpresa, 17));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title(nombre)
                .snippet(direccion)
                .position(mapaEmpresa));

    }
}
```

Comment: "*funciona bien en algunos celulares y en otros no*" <-- Es un poco genérico. ¿Podrías agregar una descripción que permita entender qué estás preguntando? Ponete en el lugar de alguien que lee tu pregunta, intentando que sea más fácil ayudarte

Comment: la app esta en modo beta https://play.google.com/apps/testing/mx.placelist.placelist   cuando la bajan de ai no funciona el mapa, y cuando la instalo desde mi pc usando mi proyecto de android studio funciona todo bien.

Comment: ¿Estás usando el mismo API_KEY para el mapa? Recuerda que debes generar uno cuando pones una app en la tienda

Answer (score 1):

Cuando instalas desde tu pc, la aplicación se firma con el Keystore de debug, y seguramente tienes definida tu API KEY de google maps definida dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXm_JBY" />
```

pero la creada con el SHA-1 del Keystore de DEBUG.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**debes crear otra API KEY con el certificado SHA-1 obtenido de tu Keystore de producción, con esa API KEY generas tu proyecto nuevamente y debe funcionar sin problema.**

Si usas tu API Key creada con un certicado SHA-1 de un Keystore el cual no es el usado para firmar tu aplicación en producción, no se mostrará el mapa en producción, **únicamente se mostrara el mapa si la subes desde tu pc ya que por default se firma con el Keystore Debug (debug.keystore)** el cual esta ubicado en `C:\Users\<USUARIO>\.android`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando agregues tu API Key creada con el certicado SHA-1 del Keystore con el cual firmas tu aplicación para la google Play Store, tu mapa se mostrara sin problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1):

El problema es que el API de Google Maps esta habilitado para trabajar con un determinado key en un proyecto de Google Cloud, que consitnene solo tu "SHA de debug". Aclarando:

Cuando creaste ese key para el API de maps te pidió el SHA de tu keystore "debug", esta es la firma que tienen los APK que se generan desde tu PC. Por eso funciona solo en tu PC.

Por otro lado, cuando creaste un APK para Google Play te pidió que crearas un keystore, este tiene un SHA distinto y es el que se usa para firmar la app que esta en Play.

Para que funcione la app en Play simplemente debes agregar el SHA que corresponde al keystore con el que firmaste para subir a play a la configuración en Google Cloud (el key que usas para acceder a Google Maps).[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]